# Concatenation: string, cons and variable

Tags: php, concatenation

I have such string:

```
$value = "@({$field}) $value";
```

I would add to field post-fix which is const:

```
\App\Model\Post\POSTFIX
```

I cann't use `.` because I ahve `{ }`

Comment: What do you expect to have in the output?

Answer (score -1):

Who told you that?

```
$value = "@({$field}) $value" . \App\Model\Post\POSTFIX;
```

Works just fine.